Reshaping a list as another nested list
I have the following list ( p to be some even number )
list1= Join[ConstantArray[1,p/2],ConstantArray[-1,p/2],ConstantArray[0,Binomial[NN,4]-p]]

I want to generate another list by picking one element from list1 such the output has the same shape as the list generated by the following code
list2= Table[a[i,j,k,l], {i,1,NN- 3}, {j,i+1,NN- 2}, {k,j+1,NN-1},{l,k+1,NN}]]

Consider the case when $N = 6$ then list2 will have the following output
{{{{a[1, 2, 3, 4], a[1, 2, 3, 5], a[1, 2, 3, 6]}, {a[1, 2, 4, 5],a[1, 2, 4, 6]}, {a[1, 2, 5, 6]}}, {{a[1, 3, 4, 5],a[1, 3, 4, 6]}, {a[1, 3, 5, 6]}}, {{a[1, 4, 5, 6]}}}, {{{a[2, 3,4,5], a[2, 3, 4, 6]}, {a[2, 3, 5, 6]}}, {{a[2, 4, 5,6]}}}, {{{a[3, 4, 5, 6]}}}}

In the same spirit, I want to generate a list using list1 so that both of them have the same structure. I thought of using ArrayReshape but it didn't help, maybe I was approaching it wrong. I also thought of using a loop for the same, but when NN is large, then it would be time-consuming. Is there a quicker way to do it? In fact, I realized that the best would be to generate list1 such that it already has the same shape, but I could not get my head around it.

If I understand correctly, you want list1 to have the same structure as list2, if so you can use Internal`CopyListStructure[list2, list1] (keep in mind it's undocumented, it could change in the future or crash for some invalid inputs)

Your example of list2 is not for N=4 but N=6?

I don't understand the relationship between list1 and list2. The parameter p appears in list1 but not in list2. What is the role played by the variable  p ?

Thanks. I edited N=6. Regarding the second question, consider it this way. You choose a N such that the list has $^{N}C_{4}$ terms, of which $p$ are non-zero and the rest are zero. Furthermore, of these $p$ which are non-zero half of them are $+1$ and half are $-1$.

Does this answer your question?
(It is not clear to me what "to generate a list using list1 so that both of them have the same structure" means.)
NN = 6; p = 6;
list1 = Join[ConstantArray[1, p/2], ConstantArray[-1, p/2], 
  ConstantArray[0, Binomial[NN, 4] - p]]

(* {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)

list2=Table[a[i,j,k,l],{i,1,NN-3},{j,i+1,NN-2},{k,j+1,NN-1},{l,k+1,NN}]

(* {{{{a[1,2,3,4],a[1,2,3,5],a[1,2,3,6]},{a[1,2,4,5],a[1,2,4,6]},{a[1,2,5,6]}},{{a[1,3,4,5],a[1,3,4,6]},{a[1,3,5,6]}},{{a[1,4,5,6]}}},{{{a[2,3,4,5],a[2,3,4,6]},{a[2,3,5,6]}},{{a[2,4,5,6]}}},{{{a[3,4,5,6]}}}} *)

list2 /. MapIndexed[#1->list1[[#2]]&, Flatten[list2]]

(* {{{{{1}, {1}, {1}}, {{-1}, {-1}}, {{-1}}}, {{{0}, {0}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}}}, {{{{0}, {0}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}}}, {{{{0}}}}} *)


Something like this maybe?
list2 /. Thread[Cases[list2, _a, Infinity] -> list1]
(* {{{{1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {-1}}, {{0, 0}, {0}}, {{0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {0}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}}} *)

